# Add Column Power BI from two column of different tables

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I wanna add a column calculated from two column from different tables :

table 1 :

```
  Date   ;    target;   
  19/10/2018;  52
```

table 2 :

```
Product; Duration;  
P1;             1;    
P2;             3;  
P3;             4;
```

And i wanna have something like that

```
Product; Duration;  New Column  
P1;             1;  (52/(1+3+4)*1) 
P2;             3;  (52/(1+3+4)*3)    
P3;             4;  (52/(1+3+4)*4)
```

Answer (score 1):

With DAX try this as a new column for table2:

```
New Column = VALUES('table1'[target])/SUM(table2[ Duration])*'table2'[ Duration]
```

The VALUES function will work here because there is only one value in `'table1'[target]`

When you expand table1 with more dates and targets like this:

[image]

You can use the LOOKUPVALUE function to retrieve the target for a specific date:

```
New Column =
LOOKUPVALUE ( Table1[target], Table1[Date], DATE ( 2018, 10, 19 ) )
    / SUM ( table2[ Duration] )
    * 'table2'[ Duration]
```

Or the target form the latest date:

```
New Column =
LOOKUPVALUE ( Table1[target], Table1[Date], MAX ( 'Table1'[Date] ) )
    / SUM ( table2[ Duration] )
    * 'table2'[ Duration]
```